# Why can't some users see my location limited Android app in Market?

Tags: android, location, google-play

I have published an app on Android Market which is limited to Norway.  I'm able to find and install it myself from Market, as can several other Norwegian users.   A colleague (Android 2.1) and a friend (Android 1.6), on the other hand, cannot find it.  They both have phones bought in Norway, with SIM cards from Norwegian providers.

Why are some Norwegian users able to find it, and others not?  How does Google determine the location of Market users?

The app works on Android phones with v1.5+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been issues recently with Apps not showing up on the market after being updated. 
Searching Google for this will turn up results... (Sorry, I can only post one hyperlink right now)  But this may not be the issue, as it seems that some can see it. (And Google is stating that they have fixed the issue)

The following link explains how Google determines which users to restrict based on Country:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

From the link:

When you upload your app to the Android Market, you can select specific countries to target. The app will only be visible to the countries (carriers) that you select, as follows:

A device's country is determined based on the carrier, if a carrier is available. If no carrier can be determined, the Market application tries to determine the country based on IP.
Carrier is determined based on the device's SIM (for GSM devices), not the current roaming carrier.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track!  I had <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="3"> in my manifest, which excludes a lot of small screen devices.  Now I use <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4">, and the issue is solved.